# why useState doesn't work with useEffect()?

Tags: react-native, use-effect, use-state

```js
    const [dataSortArray, setDataSortArray] = useState([]);
   
     // seeAllFeeds
     const { data, loading, refetch, fetchMore } = useQuery(SEE_ALL_FEEDS_QUERY, {
       variables: {
         offset: 0,
       },
     });
   
     useEffect(() => {
       if (!loading) {
         refetch();
         console.log(data);
         setDataSortArray(data);
         console.log("✅", dataSortArray);
       }
     }, []);
```

as you can see I use `useQuery`.

if loading is done, i refetch the query and console.log(data) then data contains some array.

and I put this array into `dataSortArray` using `setDataSortArray`.
but when I console.log dataSortArray, it's empty.

```
✅ Array []
```

do you know why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does calling react setState method not mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-does-calling-react-setstate-method-not-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: Question: is that `useQuery` hook you are using coming from `react-query` or any other library?

Comment: I think it's from ```apollo``` for ```GraphQL```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put `loading` into dependency array it will invoke every time value of loading is change passing `Empty array []` as dependency array means it will render only once

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading) {
      refetch();
      console.log(data);
      setDataSortArray(data);
      console.log("✅", dataSortArray);
    }
  }, [loading]);
```

Comment: This may result in an infinite loop. Once initial load is done, the loading state will be updated from "True" to "False", which then will trigger another refetch that will change the loading state from "False" to "True".

Comment: if you don't want to refetch after loading is false then don't put it there or is there some logic for that?

Answer (score 0):

As @Dominic have pointed out in the question's comments (with a [relevant link to another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-does-calling-react-setstate-method-not-mutate-the-state-immediately)), `useState` is not effective immediately. So if you call `setState` on `varA` and `console.log` immediately afterwards, the `varA` won't be in the latest state you would expect.

I would suggest handling the state of `dataSortArray` in a separate `useEffect`.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading) {
      refetch();
      console.log(data);
      setDataSortArray(data);
    }
  }, []);

  // Log dataSortArray when processing for setDataSortArray is completed by React.
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(dataSortArray)
  }, [dataSortArray]}
```